# Probability that a randomly chosen integer between 5 and 12 is even

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

How can i solve this question ?

An integer between 5 and 12 inclusive is chosen at random. What is the probability that it is even ?

Comment: By "at random", I assume you really mean "uniformly randomly".

Comment: Yes choosing uniformly randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many integers in the set $\{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$?

How many of them are even?

To obtain the probability of randomly choosing an even number, divide the number of even numbers by the number of elements in the set above.

Answer (score 2):

Since all events (integers between 5 and 12) are equally likely, all you have to do is count the number of events where the chosen integer is even, and divide by the total number of events. In general you would also need to weight by the probability of each event (integer between 5 and 12) before adding them up.